# Get DISTINCT results in SQL statement and ORDER BY Random

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

So I'm trying to get unique results every time and I can't get it to work properly.

The user could have multiple entries in the table but I want it to only pull 2 unique entries no matter how many each user may have in the table.

This shouldn't be that difficult. Seems to be much easier in MySQL even though it's probably non standard. Anyway, this is what I have and it still pulls multiple results. It should not allow multiple `mem_id's` that should be unique. Right now this allows the same `mem_id` for both results.

```
SELECT media_id,mem_id FROM battle_entries WHERE active='1' AND 
mem_id!=".$mem_id." GROUP BY media_id,mem_id ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 2
```

**EDIT:**

```
----------------------------------------------------
| btl_id | mem_id | posted | media_id | active |
----------------------------------------------------
```

That is what my table columns look like `btl_id` is a `bigserial`, `mem_id`,`media_id` and `posted` are `bigint` and active is `smallint`

There can be multiple rows where the mem_id is not unique because the user has multiple entries. I want to pull two random but unique rows by mem_id but also retrieve media_id in the select. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: Please, show examples of the current result and another as is expected to be.

Comment: What is the table schema? You want to group by `mem_id` but get two random `media_id`s, right?

Comment: @muistooshort this is correct.

Comment: @muistooshort I updated the answer with schema info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ON (mem_id) mem_id, media_id 
    FROM battle_entries 
    WHERE active='1' AND mem_id!=1) s
 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 2;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4fc12/1/0)

Comment: Already tried using Distinct. I get this error with your example `ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON (mem_id) mem_id, media_id FROM battle_ent...`

Comment: Well no error but it always chooses the same to rows but just alternates which appears first. So it's not really random because it's not going through the whole table.

Comment: Well, you dont need to randomly sort rows that do not satisfy where condition. Seems to work well on the fiddle I added.

Answer (score 0):

well you can use row_number:

```
with cte as (
    select
       *,
       row_number() over (partition by mem_id order by random()) as row_num
    from battle_entries
    where active = 1 and mem_id <> 1
)
select *
from cte
where row_num = 1
limit 2
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d24da/1)